# How to name this bacterial gene when running out of letters?

Tags: gene

There's a gene in some bacteria that I have to name.

My (very limited) understanding is that for bacteria, naming conventions are based a lot on Demerec et al. 1966 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1211113/pdf/61.pdf). Essentially, the point is to have a group of three letters designating a pathway or process (e.g. *abc*) and an additional uppercase letter identifying individual genes in a pathway (e.g. *abcA*, *abcB*, *abcC*...). Different alleles would be given numbers (*abcA1*, *abcA2*...). No Greek letters, superscripts, etc.

Now my problem is that for my pathway (let's call it *abc*) basically everything from *abcA* to *abcZ* exists already (some only in eukaryotes, and some were later proven to not be actually part of the *abc* pathway, but I think it would be confusing if I repeat those with a totally different gene).

I was initially thinking about using a Greek letter for it, but that's not allowed.

Does anyone know what is usually done when running out of alphabet? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would guess that as you have an alphanumeric code already set for the pathway, using abc as the pathway name and A as the initial with alleles as numerics; that you would add an additional capital letter e.g. abcAA.

Comment: @bob1 Not unreasonable, but I wonder if it has ever been done.

Comment: I favour the suggestion from @bob1. It's up to you to see if it has ever been done. I had a quick go myself, but it needs some effort as on GenBank genes tend just to be numbered. What I would try is Streptomyces coelicolor and related strains, which are known to make complex antibiotics, or other bacteria which can make exotic molecules. Good luck!